# Generalized structural type conformance in Scala

Tags: scala, structural-typing

I'm interested in the problem of conforming a specific type to a more general structural type.  Consider the following examples:

```
trait Sup

trait Sub extends Sup

type General = {
   def contra(o: Sub): Unit
   def co(): Sup
   def defaults(age: Int): Unit
   def defaults2(age: Int): Unit
   def defaults3(first: String): Unit
} 

trait Specific {
   def contra(o: Sup): Unit // doesn't conform
   def co(): Sub // conforms
   def defaults(age: Int, name: String = ""): Unit // doesn't conform
   def defaults2(name: String = "", age: Int = 0): Unit // doesn't conform
   def defaults3(first: String = "", last: String = ""): Unit // doesn't conform
}
```

In each of the non-conforming cases, a call to the method in `General` can safely be resolved to the corresponding method in `Specific`.  A more interesting practical example can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459630/scala-immutable-objects-and-traits-with-val-fields):

```
trait Versionable[T] {
   self: { def copy(version: Int): T } =>
   val version = 0
   def incrementVersion = copy(version = version + 1)
}

case class Customer(name: String, override val version: Int) 
      extends Versionable[Customer] {
   def changeName(newName: String) = copy(name = newName)
}
```

Here, the Customer's `copy` method does not conform to the signature in Versionable's self-type annotation. Note, however, that if the compiler allowed, `copy` could be invoked just as it is in `Versionable.incrementVersion`.  Clearly, the actual signature of Customer's `copy` method is too specific for use in Versionable, since it carries the irrelevant knowledge that one can optionally supply a `name` parameter.

Are there ways to work around these limitations? Are there reasons that such generalized conformance would be a bad idea?

Comment: Another practical example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410469/refactoring-copy-functionality

Answer (score 1):

One concern is that when you read this code:

```
self: { def copy(version: Int): T }
```

you do not expect the name of the parameter to be significant, as it would have to be in this example:

```
case class Robot(number: Int, override val version: Int)
  extends Versionable[Robot]
```

**EDIT**: On another note, regarding the lack of parameter contravariance for methods, you can do:

```
type General = { val contra: (Sub => Unit) }
class B { val contra = ((o:Sup) => println(o)) }
var b:General = new B
```

Comment: That's a good point.  This kind of generalized conformance should probably not be the default anyway (for performance reasons).  Requiring a `@named` annotation on the `version` parameter in the structural type would solve both problems, I think.