# Refactoring copy functionality

Tags: scala

Is it possible to refactor the following?

```
  case class Foo(
    a: List[String]) {
    def +(s: String) = copy(a = s :: a)
  }  

  case class Bar(
    a: List[String],
    b: Int) {
    def +(s: String) = copy(a = s :: a)    
  }
```

Comment: In what way? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Daniel Duplicated `def +(s: String) = copy(a = s :: a)`,
 I suppose

Comment: Duplicated code. Not a problem per se.

Comment: Seemingly duplicated code. The methods are different (they might as well have had different names), and even if their type signature was equal, they still wouldn't share a common interface.

Comment: I'd argue they are conceptually equal. They both return a copy of the class on which they are defined. Since we can describe that concept in human language, it might hyphothically be that we could describe it in a programming language as well. Such as, if we could extract the functionality to a superclass, we could (roughly) say that "subclasses of this class all have a list of strings and a method that adds a string to the list and returns an instance of the actual subclass".

Comment: This _would_ be possible if Scala supported a more general form of structural type conformance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471708/generalized-structural-type-conformance-in-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy` cannot be extracted to a super-class (if that's what you are looking for) - it's a compiler-generated method.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but was wondering if there might be some other way to redure the duplication in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this with an immense amount of reflection, in a somewhat fragile way, by using the (undocumented) `copy$default$1` methods, and matching types off of the `copy` method, and having both implement a trait that included `def a: List[String]` and `def a_=(a0: List[String])`.  But it's a bad idea; the support isn't fully there (e.g. if you mixed it into a non-case-class it would fail at runtime), it's slow, and it saves only a small amount of typing.

If you have a case where it would save a huge amount of typing, I would encourage you to use code generation instead (i.e. Scala code that writes Scala code) with an extra pass for compilation.