# this.type as a constructor argument

Tags: scala, generics, types

Following on somewhat from this question [Why cannot this.type be used for new instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775312/why-cannot-this-type-be-used-for-new-instances) . I want to have a this.type object in a constructor.  I don't believe that this can be done, however I am hopeful some one here knows a way!
This is my base trait

```
trait Node {
  def parent:Option[this.type]
}
```

and I have implemented a class as follows

```
case class NodeInstance(parentValue:Option[NodeInstance]) extends Node {
  def parent = parentValue.asInstanceOf[Option[this.type]]
}
```

but I would like to have had

```
case class NodeInstance(parent:Option[NodeInstance]) extends Node
```

But this gives an overriding method parent has incompatible type exception.

I imagine that I cannot have this as an object that inherited NodeInstance (if it was a class say), would break the this.type requirement.  However I thought I would check to see if there exists a better way around this...

now if I use

```
trait Node[T] { self:T =>
  def parent:Option[T]
}
```

And I want a function 'root' which returns the root node, if I embedded it in the trait

```
trait Node[T] { self:T =>
  def parent:Option[T]
  def root:T = this.parent.map(_.root).getOrElse(this)
}
```

Then I get the compiler exception value root is not a member of type Parameter T

If I abstract out root, I then get type parameter issues for T

```
object Node {
  def root[T <: Node[?]](node:T):T = node.parent.map(root(_)).getOrElse(this)
}
```

OK, just discovered I can have [T <: Node[T]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.type` refers to the instance type. Since you are in the constructor there is no way to determine `this.type`. You will get the error: `this can be used only in a class, object, or template`.

In these situations it's common to introduce a type parameter and a self type

```
trait Node[T] { self:T =>
  def parent: Option[T]
}

case class NodeInstance(parent:Option[NodeInstance]) extends Node[NodeInstance]
```

Comment: It is worth adding that `this.type` should only be used when we are talking about the very same object, `this` (e.g., when returning `this` in a chainable setter), and shouldn't be used to mean “some other object of the same type as `this`”.

Comment: In this case say I create a function
def getAncestors[T <: Node](node:T):List[T]
I then have a recursive type parameter issue

Comment: @JPullar what is wrong with `def getAncestors[T <: Node[T]](node:T):List[T]`?